# getting all names of files in internal storage of android phone

Tags: android, mobile, sd-card

I read a tutorial on how to get names of files in an absolute path, but now I want to get all files - for example in my internal storage-

I mean by all the files, the files which are in the folders not only in an absolute path.

for example if my internal have folders and files like that

```
/music  
/videos  
/data  
mine.png
mohamed.txt
```

and my music folder have files like

```
him.png
sir.doc
```

I want a list like that

```
mine.png
mohamed.txt
him.png
sir.docx
```

I hope some one got me.

Thanks